# VB.Net Data Set clearing

Tags: vb.net, dataset

This is a bit of an odd questions, but I'm looking through some code it does this.

```
dsLists.Reset()
dsLists.Clear()
dsLists.Tables("Lists").Clear()
```

Its throwing errors obviously on the last dsList.Tabels("Lists").Clear(), My questions is can I remove that because of the dsList.Clear above it or was the developer trying to do something else?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Perhaps `dsLists = new DataSet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataSet` can contain many `DataTable`s. The first `clear` clears everything from your DataSet.

The second line clears specific table. You can get DataTable either by name or by index: `ds.Tables(0).Clear()`

The error is a symptom that DataTable "Lists" does not exist in your DataSet.

Comment: Ok, so the tables("List").Clear is pointless to call after the dsList.Clear() Correct?

Comment: Well depends, if you not assigning a table with that name to your dataset, then probably yes. If table `Lists` is assigned to the dataset only some of the time (ie. only when some sort of condition is satisfied) then perhaps you can first check is table exists before clearing it. But having full clear and then table clear doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Yea it didn't make sense to me either, but I just wanted to double check. I will add some logic to check for the table existing just in case the developer was trying to do something. Thanks!!

Comment: Actually come to think about it, of course you have an error, because you do a full clear before. Weird. :)